# Explain why this parameter is a pointer in a class method?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, unreal-engine4

In the book by William Sheriff there is this example from the picture. I can't figure out why pass a pointer as a function parameter, if it's not used anywhere else in the body? I'm talking about `(UPrimitiveComponent * ClickedComp)`.

The book (online PDF [here](http://1.droppdf.com/files/HpLiN/learning-c-by-creating-games-with-ue4-by-william-sherif-2015.pdf)) shows the original function *as an image only* (as shown below):

[image]

However, there is a code (as text) version of the *modified* function, as follows:

```cpp
void APuzzleBlock::BlockClicked(UPrimitiveComponent* ClickedComp)
{
    // --REPLACE FROM HERE--
    bIsActive = !bIsActive; // flip the value of bIsActive
    // (if it was true, it becomes false, or vice versa)
    if ( bIsActive )
    {
        BlockMesh->SetMaterial(0, OrangeMaterial);
    }
    else
    {
        BlockMesh->SetMaterial(0, BlueMaterial);
    }
    // Tell the Grid
    if (OwningGrid != NULL)
    {
        OwningGrid->AddScore();
    }
    // --TO HERE--
}
```

The `ClickedComp` argument is not used in the body of that version, either.

Comment: Don't add images, instead paste code here

Comment: @George Without the context it is difficult to say. You need to provide class declarations.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation for having that (seemingly unused) argument is that the `BlockClicked` function is being used (elsewhere) as either a type of 'message handler' or some other form of callback routine.

In such a case, the function's signature *must* match that expected by the system which uses it as a handler and/or callback.

However, it *may* be better, in such a case, to omit the argument's name – but that's more a matter of style than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

In the Unreal Engine code base (any code base really), there are many Events that you can utilize to affect Objects/Actors.

These Events pass you information for which you can choose to use or not when implementing the function body that otherwise cannot be reached or should not be reached outside of that function body.

When overriding such Events, the function signatures must match, this is standard practice and required, however the passed in parameters do not need to be used.